# Table charset utf8mb4 not working mysql-connector-java 5.1.44 (and later)

Tags: java, mysql, connector-j

I have mysql server 8.0.21 with configuration

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
```

And a table with charset utf8mb4

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (`c0` TEXT) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

This code is working with mysql-connector-java 5.1.18

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostxxxx/test?" +
        "user=userxxx&password=passxxx");
String sql = "INSERT INTO test(c0) value ('')"; 
conn.createStatement().execute(sql)
```

But when I use mysql-connector-java-5.1.44 (or higher) -> get the error `java.io.IOException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x9A\x98\xF0\x9F...'`

I am able to get this code to work with version 5.1.44++ by changing the server config `character_set_server` to `utf8mb4`, But because backward compatible, I could not change it

Anyone know how this code working with the old version (mysql-connector-java-5.1.18) but not work with the version (5.1.44 and later)
I found some related topics to this error but could not resolve my issue

Comment: Try forcing UTF-8 encoding on the JDBC connection: `&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Comment: Any reason you're using a version 5.1 JDBC driver with a version 8.0 database? Try upgrading to an 8.0 JDBC driver.

Comment: @Andreas it is a legacy system supporting multi-customer mysql version (5.x, 8.x...), i tried with `&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`, but not working